# Append hrefs into list using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Using Beautiful Soup, I am trying to append all the links on a site into a list with the following code. However, the code seems to iterate through the link list and always add 15 times The code iterates through the link list on the site, but the output is not what I expected. Do you have any advice how to adjust the code so that each link is appended once? In the end, I'd like to have a list containing all 15 links. Thanks.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
url = 'http://www.gks.ru/bgd/free/B00_25/IssWWW.exe/Stg/d000/I000650R.HTM'
data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
page = BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
l=[]
for link in page.findAll('a'):
       l.append(link.get('href'))
       print l[0:]
```

Comment: This looks like it would add each link once. How does the output differ from what you expect?

Comment: Um, you do realize that your output, with that last line, will print all the links that have been collected so far, each time you add one? Was that your intention?

Comment: Make that an edit to the question please.

Comment: @Tom Zych, I got it... thanks, man

Comment: Outdent the `print` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments, it appears that your error was
to include the `print` statement in the loop. You wanted to print all of
the links once at the end, so the code should be:

```
l=[]
for link in page.findAll('a'):
    l.append(link.get('href'))
print l
```

Note that you only need to print `l`. `l[0:]` is equivalent.